# Prioritize network usage by app?

Tags: macos, network, icloud

I have one folder of old videos backing up via an uploader app (odrive), but it's 200 GB so it will take a few days.

While that's happening I need to upload a small (50MB) video which I need to send to a client for review (in a different folder) – NOW! – via another app (CloudApp).

So now the big backup is holding up my need-it-now upload.

Is there any way to have the 2nd app take over priority and/or "throttle" the first app until it's done uploading?

Comment: What measurement are you making to determine the big backup is holding up the other? What does activity monitor show for CPU use on the two apps and what is throttling each upload? In my experience, your computer isn't the bottleneck on either  - the CloudApp typically takes uploads slower than most consumer networks.

Comment: I can see in istat menus which app is using how much bandwidth. If both apps are uploading, they roughly split my bandwidth. I'd rather let one hog it all up when it wants to.

Comment: So - what is throttling the upload? You should be able to tell that from the aggregate and single statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing quality of service on the network client/endpoint is generally a waste of time and therefore (I presume) no one has made that sort of software for OS X.

There isn't an easy way to go in and fiddle with things without tearing down the transfers that are in progress and I can probably infer that you can't resume either transfer easily or you would have simply paused the first to see if it helped the second already.

A more viable option going forward is to use a network protocol that lets you pause one and resume a partial transfer for the long acting transfers.

- transmit.app allows you to pause transfers
- `rsync` effectively allows you to resume transfers since it can pick up a partial transfer in the middle of a large file when it gets interrupted.

Comment: Both apps are "pause-able" but I am looking for an "automatic" solution. This is something I need to do many times per day.

Comment: @Ze'ev Wow - are you saturating your internet upload link? If your billable rate is even $5 an hour, investing in a router that can do QOS for you to prioritize traffic to the CloudApp servers might be worth it to set up. You'll probably get better uploads if you control the congestion instead of overloading your ISP upload link - they generally buffer hard  and non-optimally as you may be experiencing.

Comment: My router has QoS but it's WAY over my head. Got a link to a good guide for noobs? Queues, classes ...

Comment: Nothing comes to mind - networking requires a bit of a time investment to learn how to set up and manage qos on all the hardware I've used.